# C++ data structure to combine lookup and ordered data

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable

I have a sorted graph, when I load the edges I use a hashtable to look up the vertices. The edges are sorted by source, therefore I only need to look up "deeper" vertices. If a given edge has a source vertex on level **n**, then the sink vertex  must be on level **m**, where **m > n**. I need to exploit this behaviour to improve performance.

The "ideal" naive solution would be a hashtable for each level, where I could use the level to find the correct table, then find the element within the table. This would also allow me the extra benefit of being able to reclaim memory when **n**, the source level, is greater than the level. Unfortunately the graph is too big for this approach, 10^6 levels and 10^9 vertices.

Does anyone have any suggestion on what data structure I should be looking at?
Gracias

Comment: Why do you need a hashtable at each level? What is wrong with just having an ordinary graph structure (allocate memory for each node and have a pointer from each node to each of its sinks)? This still lets you lookup any vertex, given its address, and from each vertex you can find all of the ones which it points to. Maybe I'm not understanding what operations you need to perform.

Comment: I am creating and "colouring" the graph. I have a file that contains all the edges, as I read the file whenever I encounter a new vertex, I give it a colour. The problem is I only want to colour new vertices, and I don't want to retain a "flat" hash of all the vertices. I can't find a node and lookup its neighbours, because I am still creating the graph, or rather loading it from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Given your size estimates for the problem, I would suggest a vector of vectors: The outer vector contains one inner vector for each level, so it contains about 1 million entries; the inner vectors (which contain about 1000 entries each?) should be kept in sorted order and use sorted inserts using `lower_bound()` etc.

You can reclaim memory by the copy/swap trick to replace old, unused inner vectors by empty ones.

```
typedef std::vector<Node> level_nodes;
typedef std::vector<level_nodes> graph_nodes;

graph_nodes g;
r.reserve(1000000); // OK, just a few MB

// ...

g[12].insert(std::lower_bound(g[12].begin(), g[12].end(), x), x);

level_nodes().swap(g[11]); // kill level 11 and reclaim memory
```